# GET the value of a variable with POST method

Tags: javascript, rest, spring-boot

i'm using spring boot , restful and angularsjs, i have a method to add new agent  , there is her code

```
  $scope.addagent=function(d)
      { 
            var createagent=d+"-"+Math.random().toString(36).slice(-8)+"-"+Math.random().toString(36).slice(-8);
            var req = {
                     method: 'POST',
                     url: 'http://localhost:8080/agent/addagent/',
                     data: { 'message' : createagent }
                    }
                    $http(req).success(function(data){alert("ok")});
      }
```

and there is my rest Controlleur :

```
@RequestMapping(value=("addagent/"), method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void AddAgent( String message)
{
    String[] parts=message.split("-");
    Agent ag=new Agent();
    ag.setCin(parts[0]);
    ag.setLogin(parts[1]);
    ag.setPassword(parts[2]);
    ag.setAdmin(null);
    ag.setStructurenotifications(null);

    agentservice.createAgent(ag);
}
```

but when i click on addagent() button this i get this error :

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.gatewayproject.AgentRestControlleur.AddAgent(AgentRestControlleur.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

this error refere to the

```
String[] parts=message.split("-");
```

i think that there is a problem with gettting the value of post method ?

Comment: It is just a method argument, how should it know that it needs to bind from a request parameter? You are missing the `@RequestParam` annotation on the method argument.

Comment: Please don't add code in comments, that is unreadable. Modify your post... Also what should be the result, the method is void, so it doesn't do anything for the client that is how you implemented it.

Comment: so after adding the @RequestParam , there is no error and the is no result(no agent added in tne data base ) ?

Comment: And why should it be added? I you haven't configured transactions correctly nothing will be saved.

Comment: i'm using spring boot !!!! and how can i configure transaction with spring boot ?

Comment: Your setup should then be ok but if there is no `@Transactional` on your service nothing is going to happen. Also are you using spring boot or are you using it and trying very hard to work around it by still trying to configure everything yourself?

Comment: i'm using the annotaion Transactional and Service in my service class , and i'm not trying to configure everythink ??

Comment: Then your service must be doing something you didn't expect, you are using the spring configured instance (i.e. auto wired one) in your controller and don't create instances yourself? However your initial question has been answered, the request is now processed and you now have another (unrelated) problem.

Comment: how can i test if the RequestParam String message contain value or not ? i'm trying with system.out.print() but there is no result ???

Comment: If there wouldn't be anything your method would fail, the parsing results in a correct array else it would either fail with a `NullPointerException` (no input) or an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` due to failed parsing into an array.